# ¿Porqué el archivo que genero de excel con php no se me descarga?

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel

Mi problema es que tengo mi código, en php que genera un archivo excel, y en mi servidor local funciona bastante bien, al momento que presiono el botón de generar excel lo descarga, pero una vez que lo subí mi sistema al servidor real, ya no me descarga nada, solo me abre una página con una tabla, que prácticamente sería la del excel,pero no se descarga nada.

pongo mi código para que me digan en que estoy mal:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        include_once('db.php');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es-es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Contacto</title>
        <head>
        <body>
            <?php
            // Definimos el archivo exportado
            $arquivo = 'consulta.xls';
            
            // Crear la tabla HTML
            $html = '';
            $html .= '<table border="1">';
            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td colspan="5">Reporte generado mediante consulta de carga de archivos</tr>';
            $html .= '</tr>';
            
            
            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Id</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Carpeta</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Nombres</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Fecha</b></td>';
            $html .= '<td><b>Estado</b></td>';
        
            $html .= '</tr>';
            
            //Seleccionar todos los elementos de la tabla
            $result_msg_contatos = "SELECT * FROM image";
            $resultado_msg_contatos = mysqli_query($con = con(), $result_msg_contatos);
            
            while($row_msg_contatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_msg_contatos)){
                $html .= '<tr>';
                $html .= '<td>'.$row_msg_contatos["id"].'</td>';
                $html .= '<td>'.$row_msg_contatos["folder"].'</td>';
                $html .= '<td>'.$row_msg_contatos["src"].'</td>';
                $html .= '<td>'.$row_msg_contatos["created_at"].'</td>';
                $html .= '<td>'.$row_msg_contatos["estado"].'</td>';
                
                $html .= '</tr>';
                ;
            }
            // Configuración en la cabecera
            header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
            header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
            header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header ("Pragma: no-cache");
            header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
            header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
            header ("Content-Description: PHP Generado Data" );
            // Envia contenido al archivo
            echo $html;
            exit; ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

y este es mi boton con el que genero el que mando llamar al codigo que genera el Excel:

```
        <div class="col-3" style="text-align: right;">
        <a href="generar_archivo.php" type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Submit Form"> Generar excel</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Veo que generas el excel, pero no veo un enlace desde donde descargar. Has probado a montar un enlace con la ruta del archivo? De esa forma tendría un botón/enlace donde pondrías descargar y se bajaría al pinchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comprueba esta parte, te faltaba cerrarlo

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contacto</title>
</head>
```

Yo suelo utilizar el editor Notepad++ para comprobar las entradas y salidas de bloques de código, etiquetas, bucles {} [] (), etc.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Página oficial en  [notepad-plus-plus.org](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: Sublime text te cierra la etiquetas solo. Bastante útil y gratis también.